# Have all file updated in a directory

Tags: python-2.7

I'm needing a bit of help.

I'm looking to use python 2.7 to see if all files in a directory have the same modified date.

I'll be adding this into an if statement so I'm only looking for a True & False value. So if all file have been modified then true else false.

Any help would awesome.

Update:-
The method below works but is this the most effective way?

```
import os,time

def get_information(directory):
    file_list = []
    for i in os.listdir(directory):
        a = os.stat(os.path.join(directory,i))
        file_list.append(str(time.ctime(a.st_atime))[:3])
    return file_list

def checkEqual2(iterator):
   return len(set(iterator)) <= 1

print get_information("C:\\Auto_Import\\")
print checkEqual2 (get_information("C:\\Auto_Import\\"))
```

Comment: What have you tried that didn't work ?

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow! please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour),
read up on [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking)
and provide a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
that reproduces your problem.

Comment: Still googling it to pull a solution together.

import os,time

def get_information(directory):
    file_list = []
    for i in os.listdir(directory):
        a = os.stat(os.path.join(directory,i))
        file_list.append([i,time.ctime(a.st_atime),time.ctime(a.st_ctime)]) #[file,most_recent_access,created]
    return file_list

print get_information("C:\\Auto_Import\\")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `os.scandir` for better efficiency since it pulls the information of all files in a given directory in one single call:

```
from os import scandir
def has_same_mtime(path):
    return len(set(entry.stat().st_mtime for entry in scandir(path))) == 1
```

If you're using Python 3.4 or before you would have to fall back to `os.listdir` instead:

```
import os
def has_same_mtime(path):
    return len(set(os.stat(os.path.join(path, name)).st_mtime for name in os.listdir(path))) == 1
```

Comment: I've imported the scandir whl which is not installed on Python 2.7 but the above will not run. Here is the error i get:- function has_same_mtime at 0x0214C0B0

Comment: I see. I've updated my answer with a solution for Python 2.7. Please try again.